# virsh ssh into a guest vm

Tags: kvm-virtualization

Is there anyway that I can ssh into a guest vm through virsh instead of find the ip address of the guest vm?

e.g.

what I want is ssh into a guest like this way :

```
$virsh ssh_or_somwthing <domain>
```

but not like this:

```
$ #1) find the guest vm's IP address:
$arp
...
$ #2) ssh someone@<IP>
```

Answer (score 9):

Jacek has the right answer, but just to lay out some of the specifics:

1. Log into the VM using the KVM GUI
2. On the VM command line, type in:

   ```
   systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
   systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0.service
   ```

You will be asked multiple times to enter your password/accept.

3. Reboot the VM
4. Then, from the terminal on your main machine, type in:

   ```
   sudo virsh console your_vm_name_here
   ```

Obviously replacing "your_vm_name_here" with whatever the VM name is.

Then you can "ssh" directly into the VM using `virsh`.

Comment: This allows you to access the VM via a terminal, but this has nothing to do with SSH.

Comment: `error: internal error: character device console0 is not using a PTY`

Comment: Can anyone know how to access the console without a password but a private key? I mainly ssh into the VM with PK, but via `virsh console` I had to provide the password, which I am totally unaware of.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about it, but I think you're looking to configure console access to the guest?
It may not be the only solution (not following virsh very actively and all this stuff) - but you can setup serial console on your guest, configure your supervisor and then use virsh console domain.

Anyway - have a look at this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Access - I guess it may help or at least put you in some direction.

Comment: thanks :) it seems that console access is using telnet(I'am not sure about it) ?

Comment: Not really - telnet is different story. It's actually serial connection (kind of virtualized here)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a read of SSHsetup for libvirtd

https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/SSHSetup

Seems to do what you want.

Comment: The link you provided shows how to set up ssh communications to libvirt running on another system. This uses ssh just as a tunnel between virsh (or virt-manager) and libvirt on different machines. The OP is looking to send console commands directly through virsh to the VM, using virsh as a proxy or tunnel into the VM, rather than via ssh to the VM itself. This would be useful for running a VM with no networking, but still have effectively a serial console into the VM.

Answer (score 0):

`virsh` itself does not supply `ssh` capabilities in managing the VMs*.

If we want to access the machine through `ssh`, we may only do that through the `ssh` command.

Following are the 2 steps for that.

## 1. Setting Up the SSH Access

For the first step there are 2 tracks

### Pre-Configure the Machine (eg: Cloud-Init)

We could use cloud-init (may be also preseed.cfg/kickstart ... etc.) to install the public key.

```
# Cloud-init snippet
users:
  - name: your_username
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - your_public_ssh_key
```

### Manual Configuration

1. Ensure that ssh daemon is running in the VM, if you have an interactive access, you could run `virsh console $vm_name` then set up the ssh daemon.
   If there's no interactive access you'll need to use any of the following:

   - `virt-customize` while the machine is shut off `virt-customize -d "$vm_name" --run-command "command to install ssh"`
     or
   - `expect` to send keystrokes to setup the VM, which could be found in the appendix of this answer.
     or
   - any other tool that sends keystrokes to the VM
2. Install your public key into the VM:

   ```bash
   # virt-copy-in requires the virtual machine to be stopped
   #   for example this should return `shut off`
   virsh dominfo my_vm | grep State | awk -F':' '{print $2}' | sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//; s/[[:space:]]*$//'
   # virt-copy-in takes a file argument and a directory argument
   # thus we need to use a correct filename before copying
   if [ ! -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa ]; then
       ssh-keygen -t rsa -N "" -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   fi
   cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /tmp/authorized_keys
   # Finally, virt-copy-in may require sudo
   virt-copy-in -d "$vm_name" /tmp/authorized_keys /home/ubuntu/.ssh/
   ```

## 2. Accessing the VM

1. Capture the IP address:

   ```bash
   export vm_ip_address=$(virsh domifaddr my_vm | awk '/ipv4/ {print $4}' | awk -F'/' '{print $1}')
   ```
2. ssh into the machine

   ```bash
   export vm_user=ubuntu # set the correct username here
   ssh $vm_user@$vm_ip_address
   ```

* `virsh` could use `ssh` to communicate with remote servers, but that has nothing to do with accessing the virtual machines themselves.

## Appendix

Following is an expect snippet that could be used to automate setting up the interactive console access in a non-interactive manner.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Function to wait for a specific string before sending the command
proc wait_for_prompt { } {
    expect "# "   ; # Modify the expected prompt if needed
}

# Function to send a command and wait for the output
proc send_command { command } {
    send "$command\r"
    expect "# "   ; # Modify the expected prompt if needed
}

# Replace 'vm_name' with the actual name of your virtual machine
set vm_name "my_vm"

# Replace 'your_command' with the command you want to run inside the VM
set command_to_run1 "sudo apt-get install openssh-server."
set command_to_run2 "sudo systemctl start ssh"
set command_to_run3 "sudo systemctl enable ssh"

#spawn virsh start $vm_name 
# Spawn the virsh command
spawn virsh

# Wait for the virsh prompt
expect "virsh # "

# Start the virtual machine
send "start $vm_name\r"


send "console $vm_name\r"

# Wait for the console to start
# Send double enters
send_command ""
send_command ""
expect -timeout 100 "ubuntu login"


# Set password
send_command "ubuntu"
send_command "ubuntu"
# we may need to login again if prompted
send_command "ubuntu"
send_command "ubuntu"

# run the commands
send_command "$command_to_run1"
send_command "$command_to_run2"
send_command "$command_to_run3"

# Wait for the output of the command to appear
expect "your_expected_output" ; # Modify this line to match the expected output

# Exit the console
send "\x1d"
expect eof
```